# LSApplicationQueriesSchemes included, still app rejection ios

Tags: ios, app-store, ios9, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have two apps live on App Store, App1 and App2. Both these apps from same developer/company as it uses same iOS distribution certificate.
App1 has urlschema  "app1".
App2 has urlschema  "app2".

I used to open App2 from App1 using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"app2://"]`
```

and vice versa for opening App1 from App2.

Going along with apple guideline for URL schema using `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`

I have app1 Info.plist file with this key set as:

```
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string></string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>app2</string>
</array>
```

similarly for opening App1 from App2.

Now App2 is live in App Store. I submitted update for App1 and got rejected by apple saying:

[image]

Now few things I need to ask and have in mind.

1) Why my app is still rejected, even though I specified url scheme and I only call "app2://" from `canOpenURL:`. I dont call anything else.

2) from App2, i call:

```
NSString *customURL = @"app1://";
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{
    NSString *urlstr=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"app1://sentieo.com?type=filing&ticker=aapl"];
    urlstr=[urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlstr]];
}
else
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-store/id343434?mt=8"]];
}
```

It checks if App1 is installed or not. If no it takes it to its iTunes page.

Things on my mind :

1. List item

urlschema has "app1"
so if i call "app1://xyz" where xyz is parameter, does it takes it as different url schema which is not in my LSApplication list.

Please help. My app is in rejection mode.

Comment: Are you using `iHasApp` as mentioned in the rejection notice?

Comment: no I am not. i searched for "ihasapp" nothing.
I searched for "Canopenurl" in my project. it gives the  same code written above.
I dont use ihasapp. have used libraries like shinobi etc. but pretty sure nobody does things like that.

Comment: If you are not using iHasApp, reply to the rejection in iTunesConnect and explain what you are really doing.

Comment: so let me describe more.
when my App1 was "in review", they reported the same issue.
I replied in resolution centre that i properly went with their guidelines.
they approved the app.

now after releasing it, in a week time they reported the same message again.

Is i am missing anything ?
and pramaters in "app1://xyz" is ok ?